# C++ how can I check if a string contains a special character, then a specific character after?

Tags: c++, string

I'm a beginner programmer trying to have a user enter an email in a text field. In the text field I would like to:

A) Ensure the user has entered an @ symbol somewhere in the field
B) Ensure the user has entered a . somewhere after their @ symbol

Is there some way to do this? I'm having a hard time looking for my own answers online because of how specific it seems.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe show some code you have tried. If you are using the `std::string` type for your text field, then there are fairly easy ways to check things like this.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over values in a string? This is the first step before doing the rest. Then it's all about finding the characters, and finding where other characters are compared to that. Come back with what you've tried, and with maybe a more precise question.

Comment: @ShadowMitia I do not. I haven't coded anything because I'm not sure where to start. I was hoping I could be pointed in the direction of some resource materials to read or watch to learn how.

Comment: You're looking for [std::string::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find). (A web search for "C++ find character in string" turns up many suggestions. I suspect that your searching was too specific.)

Comment: email format is more complicated than that. and generally, best way to validate email address is just to send mail (and you probably have to send it anyway). (Boring when your valid email address is rejected just because it is not "traditional").

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::string`:

```
std::string::size_type position = text_field.find(special_char);
if (position != std::string::npos)
{
   // special char is found.
   if (position + 1 < text_field.length())
   {
       if (text_field[position + 1] == specific_char)
       {
            // Specific char found.
       }
   }
}
```

You may want to make a copy of the text field data type into a `std::string` before using the above code.

Comment: The title of the question is ambiguous, but the text says that the specific character should be "somewhere after" the special character. This code checks whether it's immediately after.

Comment: Before the OP's edit, the question stated to look at the next character.

Answer (score 0):

To check for a specific character, use

```
std::string text = "whatever text @ something.com";

auto pos = std::find(text.begin(), text.end(), '@');
```

If `'@'` appears somewhere in `text`, `pos` will point at the location of the first occurrence.

Having done that, to search for another character that follows the first one, just use the same approach, starting at the position of the first character:

```
auto res = std::find(pos, text.end(), '.');
```

If both searches succeeded, `res` will point at the first `'.'` after the first `'@'`. If either search failed, it will point past the end of the string:

```
if (res == text.end()) 
    std::cout << "match failed\n";
else
    std::cout << "success\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>


    int main()
    {
    std::string email;
    std::cin >> email;
    
    bool at_the_rate = false;
    bool dot = false;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < email.size(); ++i) {
            if (email[i] == '@')
                    at_the_rate = true;
            for (int j = i+1; j < email.size(); ++j)
                    if(email[j] == '.')
                       dot = true;
    }
    
    if ( at_the_rate && dot)
            std::cout << "this is valid email." << std::endl;
    else
            std::cout << "this is not a valid email." << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
    
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

[Meme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWqnx.jpg)

If my memory serves me, then the true regular that checks for the validity of E-Mail takes 100500 lines, you decide you really need to check whether the e-mail is valid, or does it just meet your deep subjective requirements?
But i still tried to make it a REGEX.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
 
bool CheckEmail(const std::string &str)
{
    return std::regex_match(str, std::regex("([\\w-\\.]+)@((?:\\w+\\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})"));
}
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << CheckEmail("abra@a.ruuqq") << std::endl;
}
```

will be useful ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/regex-functions?view=msvc-160

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9K4N6MO_R1Y

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As written, `R"(.*@.*\..*)"` match OP requirement (but as you said, not email validation).